# Bootstrap dropdown element with two items inside

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is what our dropdown looks like now:
[image]

We want it to be like this:

[image]

Here is our current code:

```
<li>
  <a target="blank" class="pull-left dropdown-menu__split-li-left" href=""><i class="fa fa-link margin-right-5 text-muted"></i>
Public Invoice View</a>
  <a class="pull-right dropdown-menu__split-li-right" data-clipboard-text="" href="#" title="Click me to copy to your clipboard"></a>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</li>
```

We're using Bootstrap 3 and here is some custom CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu__split-li-left {
  margin-right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: inherit;
}

.pull-left {
  float: left;
}
```

How do we make Public Invoice View and it's associated icon on the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tftj7oxy/)

```
<li class="dropdown-item item">

            <a target="blank" class="" href="#">
            <i class=" fa fa-link icon"></i>
             Public Invoice View</a>
            <a class=" fa fa-clipboard clip" data-clipboard-text="" href="#" title="Click me to copy to your clipboard"></a>
</li>
```

---

```
.clip {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I made the clipboard icon `position:absolute` and gave the entire `li` item some padding-right to accommodate the clipboard icon.

This will ensure that the icon always remains to the right even if the text is long.

Also the **dropdown** will take the width equal to maximum width of the text.